# How to retrieve post ID for a post i've just made via the Facebook API

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am using the following code to publish to a Page's `feed` connection

```
    $attachment = array('message' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            'name' => 'cccccccccccccccc',
            'caption' => 'cccccccccccccccc',
            'link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/manydldotnet/',
            'description' => "ccccccccccccc",
            'picture' => "'cccccccccccccccc'",
            'actions' => array(array('name' => 'Download!','link' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/manydldotnet/'))
            );

$result = $facebook->api('/121468571287906/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

so the question is how to get the post_id after posting it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Post's id is stored in `$result['id']`.

It's the return value of the call to `feed`; this is also the case for `/links`, `/photos`, etc.

Ref: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

Answer (score 0):

Check the value in the $result variable, that should be the actual post_id value.