# How to retreive photo ID on post event?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to retrieve post ID for a post i’ve just made via the Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813500/how-to-retrieve-post-id-for-a-post-ive-just-made-via-the-facebook-api)

I'm experimenting with the Facebook C# SDK and would like to find what variable to use to display a photo in my app once I post it to the wall. I know I need to find the ID of the photo, but I haven't had much luck. I tried using `_lastMessageID` but it didn't work. Here's the code I'm using sans the requisite variable in `postedPictureUrl`:

```
private async void PostToWall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
        parameters.message = txtMessage.Text;

        StorageFile imageFile = await Windows.Storage.StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Images/photo.png"));
        IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await imageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
        var reader = new Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader(fileStream.GetInputStreamAt(0));
        await reader.LoadAsync((uint)fileStream.Size);
        byte[] pixels = new byte[fileStream.Size];
        reader.ReadBytes(pixels);
        parameters.picture = new FacebookMediaObject
        {
            ContentType = "image/png",
            FileName = "photo.png",
        }.SetValue(pixels);
        dynamic result = await _fb.PostTaskAsync("me/photos", parameters);
        _lastMessageId = result.id;
        txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
        btnDeleteLastMessage.IsEnabled = true;
        string postedPictureUrl = string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/photos?&access_token={2}", _userId, _fb.AccessToken"); //this is where I need to retrieve the id of the photo...
        myPostedPainting.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(postedPictureUrl));
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException ex)
    {
        // handle error message
    }
}
```

Comment: After successfully uploaded, API returns the photo ID in result JSON.

Comment: _lastMessageID is returning the photo ID, I only need to find the correct path.

Comment: Found the path on my own and it works great!