# how to know the post id base on url given?

Tags: php, facebook

I want to use facebook php api to post a comment,
but I only know the page url, no post id,
how to know the post id base on url given?

```
$post_data=array(
    'message'=>'post a comment test',
    'link'=>'http://www.persunmall.com/p19000', // how to know post id
);


// how can i know the post id base on the link?
$facebook->api('/'.$post_id.'/comments','post',$post);
```

Comment: Could you make your question more clear? I don't get what `post id` is.

Comment: do you mean you want extract dynamically `p19000` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post ID can be found in the array returned from the call to `$facebook->api`.

For example:

```
$facebook->api(<your API call>);
```

Then you can find the post ID in $result['id'] when making a call to 'feed', as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7813500/how-to-retrieve-post-id-for-a-post-ive-just-made-via-the-facebook-api)

```
$result = $facebook->api('/121468571287906/feed/','post',$attachment);
```

Additionally, Facebook's API returns a response object, which will contain a post ID for the original call. Try adding a return value to your original call, and then examining that. For example, examine the details of $returnObject for this code:

```
$returnObject = $facebook->api('/'.$post_id.'/comments','post',$post);
```

Please refer to the [Facebook API reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/) for details.